# How does angular-app reference its dependencies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm in process of learning Angular, so please forgive my naivety...

[app.js](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/app.js) in the angular-app example app references various dependencies in client/src/commmon/, such as services.breadcrumbs. How does Angular know to pull in these dependencies from the "common" directory? Is there some configuration I'm not seeing in this app?

Pertinent code:

```
angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
  'projectsinfo',
  'dashboard',
  'projects',
  'admin',
  'services.breadcrumbs',
  'services.i18nNotifications',
  'services.httpRequestTracker',
  'security',
  'directives.crud',
  'templates.app',
  'templates.common']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/index.html

There you will see the following lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/mongolab.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.name') %>.js"></script>
```

This is where all of the packages are loaded. This is set up by Grunt, which is configured to concatenate JavaScript files together and create the files which are actually served. You should take a look at the Grunt configuration file (https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/gruntFile.js) to see how it is configured to do this. I don't know too much about Grunt yet, but if you know for what to look, you can find the configuration for concatenating various sets of files which are then placed in the distribution directory under the above referenced file names.

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes sense. I should have looked at the built HTML. Missed that. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Angular dosen't have a dependency loader (yet).
all the script is being loaded from the first beginning. either as a bundle script, multiple `<script>` tags or being manual bootstrapped by another script loader

if I would create an angular app and want to use your code above, i would have to write

```
angular.module("myOwnApp", ["app"])
```

Now my app is a dependency of yours
and your app is depends on ngRoute, proj... so i have to load all your modules one way or the other

Answer (score 0):

this is what I understand

Simply speaking, when you call:

```
angular.module('app',[
  'ngRoute',
  'projectsinfo'
]
```

angular will know you create a module `app` with dependencies of `ngRoute` and `projectsinfo`.
So when `app` is initiated, it will ask for these two dependencies from `$injector`, which is responsible for module dependencies.

So, when `$injector` is asked for these two module, it just look for them by the names, from something like a module POOL, `$provide`.

Simply put,  when you define a module

```
angular.module('projectsinfo',[])
```

it actually just put a factory function, with the name `'projectsinfo'` into the POOL. And the $injector will look for modules from it.

About the `common` derectory, since you load angular.js at the very beginning, so wherever you define a module by `module`, they all goto the same pool

Answer (score 0):

In your example, services.breadcrumbs is not loaded from client/src/commmon.  The scripts in client/source/common are loaded into the browser.  On browser load, the scripts add themselves to the angular runtime (e.g. angular.module('service.breadcrumbs', [...])).  Once a module is added to the angular runtime it is available for consumption by other angular modules.